# OnPaint method not called for Child Controls - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, onpaint

I am using a Control. I have added two Panels in it as i would like to draw the multiple panels over a control. i overrided OnPaint() method for those two panels, but OnPaint() method of the first panel added to the control alone called, OnPaint() method not called for the second panel that i added to the control.

Note: I have used the below code to redraw the surface to avoid flicker issues. If i remove the below codes from my sample, OnPaint() method called for the second panel, but the element drawn in the second panel is not in Visual. (i.e,) Not displayed.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.Selectable |
                     ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

How can i achieve multiple panels drawing on a single control? Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
public Class VContainer : Panel

{

public CPanel CPanel;

public SPanel SPanel;

public VContainer()

{

this.CPanel = new CPanel();

this.SPanel = new Spanel();

this.Controls.Add(Cpanel);  **// first added Panel**

this.Controls.Add(SPanel);

}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)

{

this.CPanel.Invalidate();

this.SPanel.Invalidate();

this.SPanel.Update();

}

}

public class CPanel : Panel

{

public CPanel()

{
// Used to redraw the surface to avoid flickering issues
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                           ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                           ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

}

**// OnPaint() called since Cpanel is added first to the VContainer**

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)

{
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rect(0,0,50,50));

base.OnPaint(e);

}

}

public class SPanel : Panel

{

public SPanel()

{
// Used to redraw the surface to avoid flickering issues
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                           ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                           ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
}

**// OnPaint() method is not called while invalidating the Panel since the Spanel is added as second control to VContainer**

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)

{
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rect(0,0,50,50));

base.OnPaint(e);

}

}
```

Comment: Please show the OnPaint code, also show code wher you put a panel in another. Otherwise help is difficult

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN - I have shown the code that i tried.

Comment: to me I got your code working, did you try it ?

Answer (score 0):

Venkatesan,

Your two controls `CPanel` and `SPanel` are at the same position.

So one overlaps the other and Winforms doesn't draw the one under.

Change the positions and sizes of the controls, and you 'll see something :

```
public VContainer()
{
    this.CPanel = new CPanel();
    CPanel.Top = 0;
    CPanel.Left = 0;
    CPanel.Width = 50;
    CPanel.Height = 50;
    this.Controls.Add(CPanel);  // first added Panel**


    this.SPanel = new SPanel();
    SPanel.Top = 50;
    SPanel.Left = 50;
    SPanel.Width = 50;
    SPanel.Height = 50; 
    this.Controls.Add(SPanel);
}
```

By the way, change the order of the instructions of the OnPaint method.
Because if base class makes some drawing, it will cover what you do :

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
}
```

Full source to working solution : http://1drv.ms/1NtIttW

Regards